# Display different content per option dropdown item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a dropdown menu that I am going to put some questions in. I have also created some divs that contain the responses to the questions in the dropdown menu.

I want the answers to all be hidden when an option hasn't been selected. When an option is selected however I want only the answer to that question that has been selected to appear underneath the dropdown menu.

Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Here is my dropdown list & content:

```
<select name="questions" id="faq-questions">
    <option>Questions</option>
    <option value="1">Question 1</option>
    <option value="2">Question 2</option>
    <option value="3">Question 3</option>
    <option value="4">Question 4</option>
</select>

<div class="answer-1" hidden>
    <p>Answer 1 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer-2" hidden>
    <p>Answer 2 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer-3" hidden>
    <p>Answer 3 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer-4" hidden>
    <p>Answer 4 content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display content depending on dropdown menue user selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115916/how-to-display-content-depending-on-dropdown-menue-user-selection)

Comment: Google "Display different content per option dropdown item", the title of this question comes up with the answer (excluding this page).

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="questions" id="faq-questions">
<option>Questions</option>
<option id="option1" value="1">Question 1</option>
<option id="option2" value="2">Question 2</option>
<option id="option3" value="3">Question 3</option>
<option id="option4" value="4">Question 4</option>
</select>

<div class="answer-1" id="answer1" hidden>
    <p>Answer 1 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer-2" id="answer2" hidden>
    <p>Answer 2 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer-3" id="answer3" hidden>
    <p>Answer 3 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer-4" id="answer4" hidden>
    <p>Answer 4 content</p>
</div>
```

Now that everything has a unique ID. You can trigger an .show() or .fadeIn() whenever a select button is selected.

Something like:

```
$('#option1').click(function(){
    $('#answer1').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Or something in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your answer classes and add ids. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5o5f5d9/1/

By making all the answer divs have the same class, you can hide them all, and then only trigger the answer you want by the id. The id is a combination of the word answer and the number it refers to.

HTML:

```
<select name="questions" id="faq-questions">
    <option>Questions</option>
    <option value="1">Question 1</option>
    <option value="2">Question 2</option>
    <option value="3">Question 3</option>
    <option value="4">Question 4</option>
</select>

<div class="answer hidden" id="answer1">
    <p>Answer 1 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer2">
    <p>Answer 2 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer3">
    <p>Answer 3 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer4">
    <p>Answer 4 content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#faq-questions').on('change', function(){
        var theVal = $(this).val();
        $('.answer').addClass('hidden');
        $('.answer#answer' + theVal).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="questions" id="faq-questions">
    <option>Questions</option>
    <option value="1">Question 1</option>
    <option value="2">Question 2</option>
    <option value="3">Question 3</option>
    <option value="4">Question 4</option>
</select>

<div id="faq-answers">
  <div class="answer-1" hidden>
      <p>Answer 1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-2" hidden>
      <p>Answer 2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-3" hidden>
      <p>Answer 3 content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-4" hidden>
      <p>Answer 4 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#faq-questions').on('change',function(){
    $('#faq-answers div').hide();
    $('.answer-'+this.value).show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this little code:

https://jsfiddle.net/r4fpz8j8/

```
$('#faq-questions').change(function(){
    var question = $(this).val();       
    $('.answer').css({display: 'none'});
    $('.answer-'+ question).css({display: 'block'});
});
```