# Select and Option in a html/php page

Tags: php, html

I've got this issue
In a simple html/php page I should create something like that:
Selection of Italian Region

```
select name="" value=""
option value="0">Abruzzo</option
option value="1">Basilicata</option
option value="2">Calabria</option
....                    
/select
```

After this selection, when user chose the one, I have to show a specific list of Reseller.
How can I set it in Php/Html? can someone write to me an example of the code ?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to search online ..but I haven't found nothing ...any link that explain to me the code I should use so I try?

Comment: You could show/hide different parts of a page depending on which value is chosen using JS and adding/removing CSS classes... or you could use something like React... or you could use another framework which pulls HTML data from a server depending on what option is selected... I think what @Dragonthoughts is saying is that you need to provide code which isn't working and ask for help in fixing it. Your question will be flagged if you just ask for resources from other sites. Having said that, you could start with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781301).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Dropdown menu and on user select you would want to display a list of results based on the user selection, there are few options you can use.

Using simple php and javascript.

- > Use Javascript or jQuery onClick function.
- > Once user selects an option trigger javascript to reload the page with id=selected value
- > On a page refresh use php function ISSET . If id in your url is set display the result by calling database and retrieving the data.

Using AJAX and jQuery

- > Again use Onclick or on select or onChange jQuery function
- > If user selects or changes the drop down value trigger ajax call via jQuery
- > Write a php function (or a page) where it retrieves data from database.

  eg:
  `function getData($option){ --retrieve data--}`
- > After you retrieve Data use an id tag to display the list of results on your page.

Comment: Thanks! the point is i am in a Wordpress page, so I can use only HTML ...no Js or jquery :(

Comment: @MircoCervi Try looking here: [How to Easily Add JavaScript in WordPress Pages or Posts](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/)